# why the result of '*s-*t" in the while loop is "67"?

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

please i can't understand the while loop , why the loop show A two time and not one

```
char *s,*t;
s="ABC";
t="AA";
do {printf("A");}
while(*s++==*t++);
printf("%d %d",*s-*t);
```

Comment: So which one is the question? The displaying A twice or the 67?

Comment: Indeed - one question per post, please. For the "why does it display twice" you should think consider why you're using `do/while` instead of `while`... and what the result of `*s++` is.

Comment: the displaying A and the 67

Comment: Please format your code-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `do...while` loop always runs at least once.  So on the first iteration, `A` gets printed.  In the condition `s` points to the first character in its string (`A`), and `t` points to the first character in its string ( also `A`).  So it compares `('A'=='A')` which is true, then `s` and `t` are both incremented to point to the second character in each string (`A` and `B` respectively).

On the second iteration, another `A` gets printed.  In the condition it compares `('B'=='A')` which is false, then `s` and `t` are both incremented to point to the third character in each string.  Since the `t` string only contains two characters, `t` actually points to the NULL byte at the end of the string.

In the `printf`, it subtracts the value pointed to by `s` (`C`) by the value pointed to by `t` (a NULL byte, which in your implementation is `0`).  The ASCII value of `C` is `67`, and `67 - 0 = 0`, so `67` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
printf("%d %d",*s-*t);
```

invokes undefined behavior as you're not supplying enough argument to sate the supplied format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

> why the loop show A two time and not one?

The first time after the `do`, the print occurs unconditionally.  Then the test occurs, and the condition is true (A == A).  So the loop starts again, printing `A` the second time.  After that, the test occurs again, and the condition is false (D != A), so the loop terminates.

Answer (score 1):

It prints `67` because (a) you are using the `%d` decimal number output format, and (b), after the loop ends, `*s == 'C'` and `*t == '\0'`, and the difference of their ASCII values is `67`.